# how to get value in "reasons" field?

Tags: python

I have a variable output which can take the values #1,#2 ,
i am trying to get the value in "reasons" IF IT EXISTS,as you can see from #1 it does not exist always, can anyone suggest how this can be done?

```
output =
#1: {"took":42,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}
#2: {"took":88,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"dispatcher","_type":"lookaheadDV","_id":"832238","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"reasons": ["12345 is associated with data in an invalid state"]}}]}}
```

OUTPUT:-

```
12345 is associated with data in an invalid state
```

Comment: what datatype is `output`?

Comment: Indeed, the `['hits']['hits']` is a list

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - i tried to print output['hits']['hits']['reasons'] ,it gives an error string indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 0):

Well, start with the logic:

`hits` inside `hits` may always be there... In additions `hits` looks to be a list, so you can test if `hits` (inside `hits`) is present and if it's not empty (you could test its length, for example).

Once you know that `hits` is there, you have to go inside that object and check if the value you're looking for is there.

When you have a dictionary in Python, you can retrieve values using the following syntax:

```
new_value = some_dictionary.get('some_key', None)
```

That value "None" at the end is the value Python gives me back if there is no value associated with that key. You can put whatever value you want in there and then check for it later on:

```
new_value = some_dictionary.get('some_key', 'BETTER ASK STACKOVERFLOW')
```

You have to just try stuff. Use the REPL.

Also, the following is not anything I've ever seen in Python. What gave you this error message:

```
12345 is associated with data in an invalid state
```

Comment: `dict.get` never raises a `KeyError`; `dict.__getitem__` does.

Comment: The "output" is the value of the `"reasons"` field.  The OP apparently meant that to be the *desired* output, not the current output or an error message.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
adict = {"took":42,"timed_out":False,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":"null","hits":[]}}
bdict = {"took":88,"timed_out":False,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"dispatcher","_type":"lookaheadDV","_id":"832238","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"reasons": ["12345 is associated with data in an invalid state"]}}]}}

def get_reasons(some_dict):
    output = ""
    try:
        output = some_dict.get("hits").get("hits")[0].get("_source").get("reasons")
    except:
        pass
    return output

print get_reasons(adict)
print get_reasons(bdict)
```

prints nothing for the first dictionary and prints

```
12345 is associated with data in an invalid state
```

for the second dictionary.

PS: I changed `false` to `False` and `null` to `"null"` in your dictionaries.

Comment: `except: pass` is an antipattern.  It ignores `ImportError`, `NameError`, `TypeError`, etc.  You should be very specific in which exceptions you are capable of handling in an `except` block.

Comment: @BrianCain In this case I am expecting an `IndexError` to be specific, from `some_dict.get("hits").get("hits")[0]`. I tested the code on Python 2.7 and the `except` did not seem to ignore it.

Comment: The problem isn't that your specification is too narrow, it's that it's too broad.  You will get `IndexError` and ignore it but you will also silently ignore other errors that are rarely if ever appropriate to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore `KeyError`s where necessary. There are possibly multiple reasons, so the following code gathers them all to a list, then join together using `', '` as the separator.

```
value = { "took":88,"timed_out":False,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":1.0,"hits":[{"_index":"dispatcher","_type":"lookaheadDV","_id":"832238","_score":1.0, "_source" : {"reasons": ["12345 is associated with data in an invalid state"]}}]}}

reasons = []

for i in value['hits']['hits']:
    try:
        reasons.extend(i['_source']['reasons'])
    except KeyError:
        pass

reason = ', '.join(reasons)
```

Comment: i get the error--     for i in value['hits']['hits']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str --- did the above code work for you?